# sitecore: setup Order Manager for several sites

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

If I have several ecommerce sites definition in my SiteDefinition.config file.
And I would like to install Order Manager (Sitecore E-Commerce Order Manager 2.1 rev.130718.) for them.
How can I install 1 order manager and configure website definition and context name to all the ecommerce website?

Comment: What is the Order Manager?

Comment: @MarkUrsino (Sitecore E-Commerce Order Manager 2.1 rev.130718.)